# Delete old files but keep one each week/month/year

Tags: files, logs, rm

I have a folder with log-files each ~10 minutes:

```
alfred_140810-190001.json
alfred_140810-191001.json
alfred_140810-192002.json
alfred_140810-193001.json
alfred_140810-194001.json
alfred_140810-195001.json
alfred_140810-200002.json
alfred_140810-201119.json
alfred_140810-202002.json
...
```

How do I achieve this?

- delete all files older than a week but keep one per week
- delete all files older than a month but keep one per month
- delete all files older than a year but keep one per year

So I want one file for the last four weeks (4 files) one file per month (12 Files) and one per year (the same system like `rsnapshot` is sorting his backups).

Comment: any solution would help. the folder already has 4GB. optimal would be a cronjob that cleans up

Answer (score 5):

You want
logrotate http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html.

It is probably already on your system.  You just need to configure it.  However it is mainly for the purpose of purging old log files and I don't know if you can configure it to keep one file.

What you can do

create several directories `log`, `log.weekly`, `log.monthly`, and `log.yearly`

`log` being where all the log files go.  Create

- a weekly cron job that copies the latest log file from `log` to `log.weekly`,
- a monthly cron job that copies the latest log file from `log` to `log.monthly`, and
- a yearly cron job that copies the latest log file from `log` to `log.yearly`.

Then configure logrotate appropriately for the different directories.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    NOW=$(date +%


    ls -rt1 ${LOG} | while read FILE
    do
        TVAL=$(stat --printf %W ${LOG}/${FILE})
        if [ $(ls -1 ${LOG.WEEKLY} | wc -l) ] -eq 0 ]
        then
             cp ${LOG}/${FILE} ${LOG.WEEKLY}/${FILE}
        else
             LAST_WEEKLY=$(ls -t1 ${LOG.WEEKLY} | head -n 1 | stat --printf %W)
             if [ $((${TVAL}-${LAST_WEEKLY})) -gt $((60*60*24*7)) ]
             then
                 cp ${LOG}/${FILE} ${LOG.WEEKLY}/${FILE}
             fi
        fi
   # repeat the above logic for month and year
   rm ${LOG}/${FILE} 
   done
```

Comment: That's a good solution for the future. But it doesn't solve shrinking my already existing folder with 4GB of logs

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would do this assuming that the logs are being created daily:

```
#!/bin/sh
day=$(date +%u)#To get a day of the week
day_num=$(date +%d) #To get the current day
month=$(date +%m) #To get the current month
year=$(date +%Y) #Get current year
date=$(date +%Y%m%d) #Get current date

if [ $day -eq 7 ] #Saving only Sunday log
then
    sunday_day=$(date +%Y%m%d) # Saving sunday day
    for (( i = 1; i < 7; i++ )) 
    do
        past_day=$(date -d "-$i day" +%Y%m%d)
        rm "alfred_"$past_date"_*" #Delete six older files so it deletes up to last monday
    done
fi

if [ $day_num -eq 1 ]
then
    for (( h = 2; h <= 31; h ++))
    do
        first_day=$(date +%Y%m%d)
        past_month=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y%m$h) 
        if [ $past_month -ne $sunday ]
        then
            rm "alfred_"$past_month"_*" #Delete all last month but keep sundays' backup and the first day of that month
        fi
    done
fi
```

For the year only keep january first log